# How can i predict Time Series of more than one product using LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I made a LSTM model that predict total value per day, but i need to do a forecasting of sales per product. Someone can help me with some example?

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful: https://unit8co.github.io/darts/examples/01-multi-time-series-and-covariates.html#Training-a-Model-on-Multiple-Time-Series. You can change your code accordingly.